# Split a list into unequal chunks specified by a dictionary

Tags: python

So here is my problem I have a list of size eleven along with a dictionary which tells us how the list should be split. So here the first index should contain the sublist [14, 10, 2, 4], the second index [12, 8, 8, 5] and so on.

```
l = [14, 10, 2, 4, 12, 8, 8, 5, 9, 2, 7]

dico = dict()
dico[0] = 4
dico[1] = 4
dico[2] = 3
dico
>>> {0: 4, 1: 4, 2: 3}
```

Eventually the expected behavior is the following

```
{0:[14, 10, 2, 4], 1:[12, 8, 8, 5], 2:[9, 2, 7]}
```

Note that retaining the order of the initial list is important.

Comment: Can you please show us what you tried to solve the problem?

Comment: instead of dict use ordereddict so that it should not jumbled every time you acess it

Comment: @tard Or don't use a stone age Python version.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Given your sample data and a reasonably young Python version (that maintains insertion order for iteration of dicts), you can simply do:

```
i = iter(l)

{k: [next(i) for _ in range(v)] for k, v in dico.items()}
# {0: [14, 10, 2, 4], 1: [12, 8, 8, 5], 2: [9, 2, 7]}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
new_d = {}
for key in dico:
    new_d[key] = l[:dico[key]]
    l[:dico[key]] = []

print(new_d)
{0: [14, 10, 2, 4], 1: [12, 8, 8, 5], 2: [9, 2, 7]}
```

Answer (score 0):

I will offer this option:

```
l = [14, 10, 2, 4, 12, 8, 8, 5, 9, 2, 7]
l2 = l.copy()
dico = {0: 4, 1: 4, 2: 3}

for key, val in dico.items():
    for j in range(dico[key]):
        if j == 0:
            dico[key] = []
        dico[key].append(l2.pop(0))

print(dico)
print(l)
```

Output:

```
{0: [14, 10, 2, 4], 1: [12, 8, 8, 5], 2: [9, 2, 7]}
[14, 10, 2, 4, 12, 8, 8, 5, 9, 2, 7]
```